# Problem with a JDBC - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, gradle, jdbc, build.gradle, minecraft-forge

When loading a JAR file on a Minecraft Forge 1.16.5 server, it cannot find the MySQL driver, even though it works fine when running the server in Eclipse.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net' }
        mavenCentral()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '5.1.+', changing: true
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:7.0.0"
        classpath group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.33'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


version = '1.0'
group = 'com.yourname.modid' 
archivesBaseName = 'modid'

java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8) 

println('Java: ' + System.getProperty('java.version') + ' JVM: ' + System.getProperty('java.vm.version') + '(' + System.getProperty('java.vendor') + ') Arch: ' + System.getProperty('os.arch'))
minecraft {

    mappings channel: 'official', version: '1.16.5'

    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')


            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'


            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')


            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'


            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        data {
            workingDirectory project.file('run')

            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'


            args '--mod', 'examplemod', '--all', '--output', file('src/generated/resources/'), '--existing', file('src/main/resources/')

            mods {
                examplemod {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

dependencies {

    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.16.5-36.2.34'

    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.33'
    jarJar(group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '[8.0.26,8.0.33)'){
        jarJar.pin(it, "8.0.33")
    }


}


jar {
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.filter { it.name.endsWith('mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar') }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes([
            "Specification-Title": "examplemod",
            "Specification-Vendor": "examplemodsareus",
            "Specification-Version": "1", 
            "Implementation-Title": project.name,
            "Implementation-Version": "${version}",
            "Implementation-Vendor" :"examplemodsareus",
            "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}


jar.finalizedBy('reobfJar') 

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "file:///${project.projectDir}/mcmodsrepo"
        }
    }
}
```

MainClass

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.command.CommandSource;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegisterCommandsEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.InterModComms;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModEnqueueEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.InterModProcessEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.server.FMLServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import net.minecraftforge.server.command.ConfigCommand;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.example.examplemod.commands.CheckBalance;
import com.example.examplemod.commands.PlayerCommandHandler;
import com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Mod("examplemod")
public class ExampleMod {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public ExampleMod() {
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::setup);
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::enqueueIMC);
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::processIMC);
        FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::doClientStuff);

        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(PlayerCommandHandler.class);
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new PlayerEventHandler());
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new MobKillEventHandler());

    }

    private void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("HELLO FROM PREINIT");
        LOGGER.info("DIRT BLOCK >> {}", Blocks.DIRT.getRegistryName());

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Failed to load MySQL JDBC driver. Make sure you have the driver JAR file in your mod's dependencies.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void doClientStuff(final FMLClientSetupEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("Got game settings {}", event.getMinecraftSupplier().get().options);
    }

    private void enqueueIMC(final InterModEnqueueEvent event) {
        InterModComms.sendTo("examplemod", "helloworld", () -> {
            LOGGER.info("Hello world from the MDK");
            return "Hello world";
        });
    }

    private void processIMC(final InterModProcessEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("Got IMC {}",
                event.getIMCStream().map(m -> m.getMessageSupplier().get()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onServerStarting(FMLServerStartingEvent event) {
        LOGGER.info("HELLO from server starting");
    }

    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
    public static class RegistryEvents {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onBlocksRegistry(final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> blockRegistryEvent) {
            LOGGER.info("HELLO from Register Block");
        }
    }

}
```

Exception

```
[13:10:11] [modloading-worker-25/ERROR] [co.ex.ex.ExampleMod/]: Failed to load MySQL JDBC driver. Make sure you have the driver JAR file in your mod's dependencies.
[13:10:11] [modloading-worker-25/INFO] [STDERR/]: [com.example.examplemod.ExampleMod:setup:64]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
[13:10:11] [modloading-worker-25/INFO] [STDERR/]: [com.example.examplemod.ExampleMod:setup:64]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:523)
```

[image]

Initially, i attempted to edit the build.gradle file, but it didn't produce any results. Also tried using Shadow, but it didn't work either.

Comment: It won't be able to find the driver if you don't shade it in, which is what the shadow task does. You say you tried using shadow, but it "didn't work". Can you expand on why it didn't work? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once and found this solution below, it works for me at the time, hope it works for you too.
(but in general shade mysql driver uses to work, but you know, Murphy's Law)

```
plugins {
   //......
}


version = '1.0'
group = 'com.bodryak.gmod' 
archivesBaseName = 'gmodmod'


jarJar.enable()

tasks.jarJar.configure { }

minecraft {.....}

dependencies {
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.2-43.2.3'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.33'
    jarJar(group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '[8.0.26,8.0.33)'){
        jarJar.pin(it, "8.0.33")
    }
}
```

Since you already have your dependency fully configured, just try to insert before **minecraft{ }**:

```
jarJar.enable()

tasks.jarJar.configure { }
```

Link to the original answer where I found this solution:
[https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/111993-mysql-connectorj-is-not-working/#comment-499204](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/search/?q=jdbc&quick=1)

Comment: Murphy's Law kicked in, it still doesn't work. When using jarJar, the server simply crashes during the loading stage. But thank you for your assistance.